# How to fork the jvm for each test in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I am working with some classes that (for some reason) can only be used once within a single VM. My test cases work if I run them individually (`fork := true`) enabled in my `sbt` settings.

If I run more than one of these tests, they fail with an exception that has to with a thread executor rejecting a task (it's most likely closed). It would be very time consuming to find out what causes the problem and even if I find the problem, I might not be able to resolve it (I do not have access to the source code).

I am currently using the `specs2` test framework, but any test framework using `sbt` would be acceptable.

**Is there any test framework for `sbt` that is capable of running each test in a `jvm` fork?**

Thoughts or ideas on possible other solutions are of course welcome.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It turns out this is fairly easy to achieve. The documentation is sufficient and can be found at [Testing - Forking tests](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Testing#forking-tests)

```
// Define a method to group tests, in my case a single test per group
def singleTests(tests: Seq[TestDefinition]) =
  tests map { test =>
    new Group(
      name = test.name,
      tests = Seq(test),
      runPolicy = SubProcess(javaOptions = Seq.empty[String]))
  }

// Add the following to the `Project` settings
testGrouping in Test <<= definedTests in Test map singleTests
```

Comment: which version of sbt does this work on? I'm using 0.13.1 and I'm not having any luck. My use case is that I'm running a play2 app and I've got some companion objects that I want to have initialized with config data on each vm run (each test) and it's definitely not doing that with this solution. Thanks!

Comment: I think sbt 0.12, The link however points to a newer version.

Comment: Ah, It looks like in my version of sbt you need to do `testGrouping in Test << ....`

Comment: @fommil I added your suggested edit that was falsly rejected.

Comment: "fairly easy! :-))))))))))))

Comment: Just another reason I detest SBT.

Answer (score 3):

Using non-deprecated syntax:

```
testGrouping in Test := (definedTests in Test).value map { test =>
  Tests.Group(name = test.name, tests = Seq(test), runPolicy = Tests.SubProcess(
    ForkOptions(
      javaHome.value,
      outputStrategy.value,
      Nil,
      Some(baseDirectory.value),
      javaOptions.value,
      connectInput.value,
      envVars.value
    )))
}
```

Comment: If you have in your sbt file `javaOptions in Test ++= Seq(...` then you will need:  
 `(javaOptions in Test).value,` in the above example.

Answer (score 2):

2023 proper syntax:

```scala
Test / testGrouping := (Test / definedTests).value map { test =>
  Tests.Group(name = test.name, tests = Seq(test), runPolicy = Tests.SubProcess(
    ForkOptions(
      javaHome = javaHome.value,
      outputStrategy = outputStrategy.value,
      bootJars = Vector.empty,
      workingDirectory = Some(baseDirectory.value),
      runJVMOptions = javaOptions.value.toVector,
      connectInput = connectInput.value,
      envVars = envVars.value
    )))
```