# how to set number of forked JVMs for integration tests?

Tags: scala, sbt

The following sets up all my integration tests to run in separate forked JVMs, which expands on [How to fork the jvm for each test in sbt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798341/)

```
fork in IntegrationTest := true,
testForkedParallel in IntegrationTest := true,
testGrouping in IntegrationTest <<= (
  definedTests in IntegrationTest,
  baseDirectory in IntegrationTest,
  javaOptions in IntegrationTest,
  outputStrategy in IntegrationTest,
  envVars in IntegrationTest,
  javaHome in IntegrationTest,
  connectInput in IntegrationTest
).map { (tests, base, options, strategy, env, javaHomeDir, connectIn) =>
  val opts = ForkOptions(
    bootJars = Nil,
    javaHome = javaHomeDir,
    connectInput = connectIn,
    outputStrategy = strategy,
    runJVMOptions = options,
    workingDirectory = Some(base),
    envVars = env
  )
  tests.map { test =>
    Tests.Group(test.name, Seq(test), Tests.SubProcess(opts))
  }
}
```

but it only runs one at a time. This is not unsurprising, because according to http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Testing.html `Tags.ForkedTestGroup` is 1 by default.

However, my attempts to customise the `Tags.ForkedTestGroup` - to enable more than one JVM at a time - are being ignored. This is what I've tried (each independently):

```
concurrentRestrictions in Global -= Tags.limit(Tags.ForkedTestGroup, 1)

concurrentRestrictions in Global += Tags.limit(Tags.ForkedTestGroup, 4)

concurrentRestrictions in Global := Seq(Tags.limitAll(4))
```

So how does one get more than one forked JVM to run tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the following snippet from your post in build.sbt

```
concurrentRestrictions in Global := Seq(Tags.limitAll(4))
```

seems to work almost as expected.

In an interactive sbt shell you can check the value of the global::concurrentRestrictions setting by entering this:

```
inspect global:concurrentRestrictions
```

On my machine without setting the limit explicitly this returns:

```
[info] Setting: scala.collection.Seq[sbt.Tags$Rule] = List(Limit all to 8, Limit forked-test-group to 1)
[info] Description:
[info]  Rules describing restrictions on concurrent task execution.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  */*:concurrentRestrictions
[info] Defined at:
[info]  (sbt.Defaults) Defaults.scala:145
[info] Delegates:
[info]  global:concurrentRestrictions
[info]  *:concurrentRestrictions
[info]  {.}/global:concurrentRestrictions
[info]  {.}/*:concurrentRestrictions
[info]  */global:concurrentRestrictions
[info]  */*:concurrentRestrictions
[info] Related:
[info]  */*:concurrentRestrictions
```

And after using the snippet you posted I see this output (I've only shown the top bit here - the rest is the same as before)

```
> inspect global:concurrentRestrictions
[info] Setting: scala.collection.Seq[sbt.Tags$Rule] = List(Limit all to 4)
...
```

So that certainly seems to be working - indeed running some simple tests with the configuration you have above indicates that a separate JVM is being used for each test class and each is run in parallel by default. Without that configuration a single JVM is used for all tests. I could get this to run tests sequentially by setting:

```
parallelExecution in Test := false
```

With this setting, the tests are run sequentially but each test class still uses it's own JVM if your previous configuration is included.

If I set:

```
concurrentRestrictions in Global := Seq(Tags.limitAll(2))
```

and then perform a test run with three test classes, the tests from two classes are run concurrently and then tests from the third class are run after one of the first two finishes. This seems to indicate that this setting is indeed controlling the number of concurrent forked tests although confusingly it also indicates that the default which matters in the initial defaults for concurrent forked JVMs is not the limit of 1 for "forked-test-group" but the limit of 8 for "all".

Comment: `parallelExecution` is a different thing. That's about running tests within a suite in parallel if they are marked `with ParallelExecution`. I am unable to get more than one JVM to run the tests at the same time.

Comment: actually, you might be right... `parallelExecution` seems to have an influence!

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought about parallelExecution too, I was surprised when it affected this :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is an SBT bug that the wrong task is being tagged. The tagged is not really the task that runs the forked JVM.

A workaround is

```
inConfig(Test)(Seq(
  tags in test += Tags.ForkedTestGroup -> 1,
  tags in testOnly += Tags.ForkedTestGroup -> 1,
  tags in testQuick += Tags.ForkedTestGroup -> 1
))
```

Then your concurrent restrictions will work as expected.

```
concurrentRestrictions in Global += Tags.limit(Tags.ForkedTestGroup, 4)
```

Comment: interesting. Have you got a ticket for the bug?

Comment: @fommil, https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/2677 It's a pretty simple change; I might have time to do it myself.