# How do I share a single object with multiple Scalatest suites?

Tags: scala, scalatest

I have a number of test files, each with their own tests. Until now, each one has a trait in which I create a configuration object.

Building that object now takes the better part of two minutes, as it has to do a lot of work calling a number of databases (don't ask - really, it has to be done).

Is there a way to share this object (tldConfigMap, below) between multiple test suites in multiple files without having to build it over and over?

Here's how I was doing it - as you can see, when brought in as a trait, load() will be called every time:

```
trait TLDMapAcceptanceIsLoadedSpec extends org.scalatest.fixture.FlatSpecLike with TLDConfigMap {

  val tldConfigMap: Map[String, TLDConfig] = load(withAttributes = true).right.get

  type FixtureParam = Map[String, TLDConfig]

  def withFixture(test: OneArgTest) = {

    withFixture(test.toNoArgTest(tldConfigMap)) // "loan" the fixture to the test
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems the small repro talked about in the answer comment never arrived. I suggest closing this as abandonned.

Answer (score 0):

You could just put it into an `object` (assuming it's really config and isn't changed by tests):

```
object TldConfigMap {
  val tldConfigMap: Map[String, TLDConfig] = load(withAttributes = true).right.get
}

trait TLDMapAcceptanceIsLoadedSpec extends org.scalatest.fixture.FlatSpecLike with TLDConfigMap {

  def tldConfigMap: Map[String, TLDConfig] = TldConfigMap.tldConfigMap // or just use it directly

  type FixtureParam = Map[String, TLDConfig]

  def withFixture(test: OneArgTest) = {
    withFixture(test.toNoArgTest(tldConfigMap)) // "loan" the fixture to the test
  }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work, as Scalatest instantiates each test suite individually, thus the object is created for EVERY test suite.

I need to find how to create the object once and give it to Scalatest to use.

Comment: No, the object should only be created once per test run, not once per suite (unless you are doing something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798341/how-to-fork-the-jvm-for-each-test-in-sbt, but this isn't a common case).

Comment: Then something is amiss, as I have debug output that fires when the object is created, and I see it fired for each of the three suites I have in my test directory.

Comment: How are you running the tests: just `test` from SBT console?

Comment: Yes. "sbt test" - terribly vanilla

Comment: Looking at code, it certainly _looks_ like it should be just using a single `ClassLoader`, and so only initialize the object once: https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/blob/3.1.x/scalatest/src/main/scala/org/scalatest/tools/Runner.scala. So I don't know what could be causing this, unfortunately, and don't have time to try and reproduce the situation. Could you update your question with code using an `object` and at least 2 suites, just in case?

Comment: Yeah, I'll code up a single, small package and test with nothing else going on after the weekend.

Comment: Do you know if there is an update on this, I am also getting the exact same issue i.e. I have fields initialised in a single object that is shared within a lot of Scala test suites and the fields inside the object gets initialised for every test suite?

I think this may be due to SBT and not ScalaTest